# Express $2017$ with minimal $8$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Anyone could express coming New Year number $2017$ with minimal set of $8$?

Like (contains 8 "8"):

$$(8\cdot8\cdot8-8)\cdot\sqrt{(8+8)}+\frac{8}{8}=2017.$$

Allowed any math symbols, standard functions, integrals, etc - with only one condition final formula must contain only 8 digits, so $\sqrt[3]{8}$ and $\log_2{8}$ are prohibited since they contain $3$ and $2$.

Comment: "*Allowed any math symbols, functions, integrals,...*"  So, if I define $f$ to be the constant function where $f(x)=2017$ for all $x$, then we have $f(8)=2017$.

Comment: Applauds, but I would expect smth more creative :)

Comment: Changed conditions to *Allowed any math symbols, standard functions, integrals, etc*

Comment: $$\frac{8!x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x}{x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x}$$

Answer (score 2):

We can use three $8$'s the following way: 
$$
-\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt8}}\right)}{\ln8}\right)}{\ln 8}
$$
where there are $3\cdot 2017=6051$ nested square roots. This can be rewritten by using the two "$/\ln8$" to convert into $\log_8$, and we get
$$
-\log_8\left(\log_8 \sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt8}}\right)
$$
This is still three $8$'s, but this time no fractions.

Comment: Can't understand how it gives 2017 - could you explain me? Log over nested roots gives 1 and...?

Comment: We have $$\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt8}=8^{1/2^{3\cdot2017}}=8^{1/8^{2017}}$$Just insert that, use all the logarithms to lower the exponents, and $2017$ is the only thing that's left in the end.

Comment: Looks like you're right - I was just trying to calculate it on Excel - and due to accuracy losing I got incorrect result

Comment: @barmaley Thats not surprising, since the difference between $1$ and $8^{1/8^{2017}}$ is $10^{-2000}$, give or take a dozen digits, which is too small for any computer to pick up on.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary approach with seven $8$s
$$\frac{8!}{\sqrt{8+8}+8+8}+\frac{8}{8}=2017$$

Comment: Couldn't go less than five(!!)
$$\lceil\sqrt{8!}+\sqrt{8!}+8\rceil+ \lceil 8\sqrt{8!}\rceil=2017$$